# Non letter name in command definition

Tags: macros, catcodes, definition

I'd like to define similar commands one with underscore the other — without. However such an approach throws me an error

```
\def\Fix#1{\mathrm{Fix}(#1)}
\def\Fix_#1#2{\mathrm{Fix}_{\,#1}(#2)}
```

I tried to change the catcode of the underscore and set it back, but `\Fix_` seemed to work exactly like `\Fix`

```
\def\Fix#1{\mathrm{Fix}(#1)}
\catcode`\_=11
\def\Fix_#1#2{\mathrm{Fix}_{\,#1}(#2)}
\catcode`\_=8
```

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first approach doesn't work because TeX can't have two definitions for the same command, so the second definition overwrites the first.  Your second approach kind-of works because you have two commands, `\Fix` and `\Fix_`, but you cannot access `\Fix_` normally.

You have to define `\Fix` to look ahead for an optional `_`.  For example, with `\@ifnextchar`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\Fix{\@ifnextchar_{\@FixU}{\@Fix}}
\def\@Fix#1{\mathrm{Fix}(#1)}
\def\@FixU_#1#2{\mathrm{Fix}_{\,#1}(#2)}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\Fix{a}$ and $\Fix_{b}{a}$
\end{document}
```

Or, much easier (and robust), with `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Fix { e{_} m }
  {\mathrm{Fix}\IfValueT{#1}{_{\,#1}}(#2)}
\begin{document}
$\Fix{a}$ and $\Fix_{b}{a}$
\end{document}
```

Both documents produce:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation why my attempts didn't work and for your solutions. I do especially like the `xparse` one.

Comment: @antshar You're welcome!  The `e` argument type for `xparse` is especially powerful if you have two tokens, for example `_` and `^` (for example `\NewDocumentCommand\Fix { e{_^} m }{\mathrm{Fix}\IfValueT{#1}{_{\,#1}}\IfValueT{#2}{^{\,#2}}(#3)}`) then when you use the command you can have the arguments in any order (you could use the command above with `$\Fix^{c}_{b}{a}$` or `$\Fix_{b}^{c}{a}$`).